# Proving existence of element in a cyclic group.

Tags: group-theory

Let $A$ be a cyclic group with generator $a$.

Assume $|A|$ = $2m$. Let $b\in A$

I'm to show that $\exists x \in A$ such that $x^2=b \iff
b^m = 1$

Is this sufficient proof?

$\Rightarrow:$
Let $x \in X$ such that $x^2 = b \to (x^2)^m = b^m = 1$, since any element $x\in X$ to the power of the order of the group is equal to 1.

$\Leftarrow:$

let $b^m = 1$

take the generator, $a$, of the group and exponentiate it to the power of $2m$:

then : $a^{2m} = 1 = b^m \to a^2 = b$. QED.

Comment: Your $\Leftarrow$ is not quite right, since $b$ might be another power of $a$. For instance, if $m = 3$, so $2m = 6$, then $a^2$ and $a^4$ both have the property of $b$. Rather, take the generator $a$, find the power $n$ such that $a^n = b$, and work from there.

Answer (score 1):

Your first part is fine.

For the second, what you're trying to show is that any element whose $m$th power is $1$ must be a square. Your current proof relies on the idea that 
$$
x^k = y^k
$$
implies
$$
x = y.
$$
But that's not generally true (indeed, it's not even true for the reals: $-2^2 = 2^2$, for instance).

You'll need to do something a bit more clever than that.

Here's a suggestion: the elements of the group are all powers of $a$, right? They are, in fact, $1, a, a^2, \ldots, a^{2m-1}$.

Suppose you showed that for every *odd*-power ones, like $a^3$, you have the property that 
$$(a^{odd})^m$$
is *not* $1$. Then the only ones for which $(a^k)^m$ can be $1$ are those for which $k$ is even, i.e., $k = 2s$ for some integer $s$. Now work from there.